# How do I print without square brackets

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

so I got this function here, and what it's supposed to do is create a file, that I can write in. the second and third parameters are lists, while the first is just the file name that I am going to create to write in. In the function, I made a for loop, and I'm looping through the `all_students_list`, which is a list, but at each index, is also a list, with the first name and last name in the list. `all_courses_list` is a list of all the courses in the school, and `Schedule` is a list that another function returns, giving us the schedule of the student. Then I added the student name and the schedule together, to write to the file. The problem is that it also prints `[]` square brackets. How can I get rid of it? I've already tried to do

```
.replace('[', '')
.replace(']', '')
```

But it doesn't work.

Here is my code.

```
def generate_student_schedules(filename, all_courses_list, all_students_list):
    with open(filename,'w') as fileout:
    
        for one_student in all_students_list:
            schedule = get_schedule(all_courses_list)
            one_line = ''
            one_line += (f'{one_student}')
            one_line += (f'{schedule}\n')
            fileout.write(one_line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `one_student` is an actual list, then you can use `" ".join(one_student)`, so overall:

```py
def generate_student_schedules(filename, all_courses_list, all_students_list):
    with open(filename,'w') as fileout:
    
        for one_student in all_students_list:
            schedule = get_schedule(all_courses_list)
            one_line = ''
            one_line += (" ".join(one_student))
            one_line += (f'{schedule}\n')
            fileout.write(one_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print a list, Python's default is to print the brackets and items in the list.  You have to build a single string of the components of the list and print that single string.  Your format string can pull out individual items or use `join` across all the items if they are all strings:

```
>>> student = ['John','Smith']
>>> schedule = ['Class1','Class2']
>>> print(student,schedule)
['John', 'Smith'] ['Class1', 'Class2']
>>> line = f'{student[1]}, {student[0]}: {", ".join(schedule)}'
>>> print(line)
Smith, John: Class1, Class2
```